# Как обработать post запрос из axios в flask?

Tags: flask, axios

В гугле просто куча инфы о каком то request.form, который соответствует input'у(?), про то как и какие headers надо добавить, чтобы работал get запрос и 0 инфы про то что мне надо

вот есть функция post запроса

```
async function _post() {
  const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/post', {'example': 2})
  console.log(response)
}
```

и есть код, который ее должен обработать(как обработать - я не нашел)

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request


@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def handle_post():
  # а принт не выведется кстати)))))
  print("request = " + request)
```

а есть cors, который на все это дело ругается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как и куда нужно вписать какие нибудь headers, чтобы обойти cors?

Comment: Вот [такое](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#:~:text=A%20Flask%20extension%20for%20handling,allowed%20headers%2C%20methods%2C%20etc.) есть

Comment: @Talleyran да я уже именно к этому и пришел, а там `чет-там-cross-origin: '*'` получается или как?